# Matplotlib - bar chart that shows frequency of unique values

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have an array like:

[1, 3, 5, 2, 12, 12, 3, 6,...] etc which varies between 1-12 that represents moths.

Now, I can plot them with

```
plt.hist(months,range(1, 13))
plt.title("Job Request per month")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")

plt.show()
```

Now, it shows count of unique values at histogram. However, I can't find a way for this with bar chart.

Full Code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():

client = MongoClient('mongodb://a12345:a12345@127.0.0.1:27017/')
db = client['newDatabase']
collection = db['jobs']
cursor = collection.find({}, {'_constructed': 1})

months = []
for document in cursor:
    if '_constructed' in document: 
        months.append(document['_constructed'].month)

print(months);
plt.bar(months, range(1, 13))
plt.title("Job Request per month")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")

plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you show a desired output? Your code works for me

Comment: Yes, but it is histogram. What I want is bar chart

Comment: `plt.bar(months,range(1, 13))`?

Comment: it says ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape now

Comment: When it is hist(), it is working. Output: https://imgur.com/a/FHjnGrz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-#
#
# Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections

data = """
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec
"""
months = data.split()

data = [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 6, 6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 10,
        6, 12, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 11, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 12, 12, 6, 2, 5, 10, 6, 12, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 11, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 12, 12]

c = collections.Counter(data)
c = sorted(c.items())
months_num = [i[0] for i in c]
month_names = [months[i[0]-1] for i in c]
freq = [i[1] for i in c]

print(c)
print(months)
print(freq)
f, ax = plt.subplots()


plt.bar(months_num, freq)
plt.title("Job Request per month")
plt.xlabel("Months")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
ax.set_xticks(range(1, 13))
ax.set_xticklabels(months)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting values from the mongodb. When I print my array, the output is: [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 6, 6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 10, 6, 12, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 11, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 12, 12, 6, 2, 5, 10, 6, 12, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 11, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 12, 12]

Comment: what you want to do with your output?

Comment: Your edit has solved my problem. It is better solution than Psidom's. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.bincount` to count the `months` first and then plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create an example months array
months = np.random.randint(1, 13, size=30)

plt.bar(np.arange(1, 13), np.bincount(months, minlength=13)[1:])
```

[image]

Comment: Same error :( ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: Okay. Solved. `plt.bar(np.arange(1, 12), np.bincount(months)[1:12])` this has fixed the problem somehow. Thanks.

Comment: For the value error, I'd add a `minlength` property to `np.bincount` so it will always count to 12.

Comment: To show odd labels, set the `tick_label` parameter. `plt.bar(np.arange(1, 13), np.bincount(a)[1:], tick_label=np.arange(1,13))`

Comment: Your solution is not general. I will not have always a numbers between 1-12. For example, I will have an array like ['cat', 'cat'; 'dog']. Your solution will not work for this case. Hence, I have chosen the other one.

Comment: @funky-nd Sure if that is the case, but your question says it's an array with numbers between 1-12. The advantage of this solution is that even if a month doesn't appear, it will still plot it for you. But it's ok choosing whichever solution works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173104/discussion-between-funky-nd-and-psidom).